# Conditional Formatting of WPF DataGrid Cell Depending on DataType

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a user control that inherits from the WPF DataGrid control and to which I pass different List of objects and, so, the columns of the grid depend (i.e. are automatically generated) on the class of object that I send through.

```
<userc:cfDataGrid x:Name="grdResults" 
    FontStyle="Normal" 
    FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" 
    FontSize="14" 
    RowHeight="30"  

    AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    Margin="12" 
    AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"  
    AlternationCount="2" 

    ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    HeaderNames="{Binding Headers}" >
</userc:cfDataGrid>
```

Now, I'd like to also pass through a list of objects that have an attribute of SolidColorBrush data type and be able to use this value to set the background colour of the cell rather than display the actual value.

I have not done much work with styles etc and so I wanted to ask if anyone could give me some pointers on how to trap a column with a SolidColorBrush datatype - and perform the action described above - without depending on the name of the column?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

CC

Comment: Hi, can you please post the piece of code you use to generat columns? Do you set AutoGenerateColumns="True" on your DataGrid or did you implement your own autocreation method?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the XAML above.

Comment: Do you want an empty cell with colored background or do you want to color all the row background?

Comment: I'm looking to get an empty cell with a coloured background and not the row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a `DataTrigger` that used a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to check if the object was a `SolidColorBrush`, and if so set the background color

Something like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- DataContext will be object for entire data row -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBrushColorProperty, Converter={StaticResource IsSolidBrushColor}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBrushColorProperty}" />
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, Rachel, and report back.

Comment: I have implemented the converter but it seems that the "targetType" parameter is always System.Object regardless of whether one of the object properties is a SolidColorBrush. Also, the "value" parameter is the whole row rather than a column value. Scratching my head!

Comment: @CaledonianCoder I forgot the data item will be the entire row, not the specific column value. You'll probably have to cast it to your data object in the converter to get the property that is supposed to be the `SolidBrushColor`, or you can simply pass it the expected property name in the binding, and make sure your Converter handles `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` or nulls (I can't remember which it will use if the property doesn't exist). I'll update the XAML in my answer for that.

Comment: Many thanks, Rachel! I think I'm almost there. So I'll mark yours as the answer.