# Customize specific row data in MyToolkit DataGrid in Universal Windows Platform App

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

I am developing windows application. In that application I am using MyToolkit datagrid. I want to  highlight the row of datagrid by making the specific cell data blink in a specific case.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647556/conditional-formatting-of-wpf-datagrid-cell-depending-on-datatype

Comment: This can't be both WPF and UWP. Please show code, it's unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors) in your project. Then use the `DataTriggerBehavior` to make the specific cell data blink in a specific case.

Firstly, you need to use this package like this:

```
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
```

Then for example you can design the cell of `DataGrid` like this:

```
<controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn  Width="0.7*" CanSort="False" Header="LastName">
    <controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="30">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="std" x:Name="std">
                        <ColorAnimation From="Red" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="lastnamePanel" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <StackPanel Name="lastnamePanel" Background="AliceBlue">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Lastname}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Mike">
                            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource std}" />
                        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lastnameTxt" Text="{Binding Lastname}"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplatedColumn>
```

When the `Text` of `lastnameTxt` doesn't equal with "Mike", then the `Storyboard` will be played. Here is the rendering image:
[image]

It's a point that you need to be care with is that a initial `Background` should be set into `lastnamePanel`, otherwise the storyboard won't be played.

Comment: Thanks .I implemented this code. But this is valuable for only column. I want to know that by giving a specific condition, the blinking effect should appear to the whole row having multiple columns.

Comment: @Pinky， would you mind if do this in the code behind, not use data binding like it in my sample? And what is your specific condition?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Effect is coming only for first row and filter condition is not working properly. Could you please share some sample examples please.